# Why kaminari pagination don't working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I want to create pagination with gem 'kaminari'.I have 2 models `Post` and `Comment`, `Comment` model belongs_to `Post` model.And I want to create pagination for model `Comment`, but what I do doesn't work.
This is my posts controller, method 'show'.

```
  def show
    @comment = @post.comments.page(params[:comments_page]).per(3)
    respond_with(@post)
  end
```

This is my view, action 'show'

```
%h2= @post.title
= @post.body
=image_tag @post.photo_url() if @post.photo?
= @post.photo_url.to_s
%h3 Комментарии
- @post.comments.each do |comment|
  %p= comment.name
  %p= comment.body
= paginate @comment
%h3 Оставить комментарий
= form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f|
  = f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Ваше имя"
  = f.text_area :body, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Комментарий"
  .pull-right
    = f.submit "Отправить", class: "btn btn-success"
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `@comments` collection into your `paginate` method. Also, you use custom pagination param name, you should specify this:

```
= paginate @comments, param_name: :comments_page
```

What's more, you should iterate over your paginated comments, not all of them:

```
- @comments.each do |comment|
```

and in controller, name your instance variable properly:

```
@comments = @post.comments.page(params[:comments_page]).per(3)
```

Comment: thank you, where paste this 'paginate @comments, param_name: :comments_page' ?

Comment: @vveare138 in view, this is the helper rendering pagination links. You have it already: `= paginate @comment`, but you should fix it the way I wrote.